# Table of structure as function parameter

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-pointers

i go some problem about modifying values of my structure created in my main in a function of another file:

Here is the structure definition in my .h file :

```
typedef struct Player Player;
struct Player
{
 char pseudo[30];
 char pawnOfPlayer;
 int numberPawn;
};
```

Here's the table declaration of Player and the function i call in my main :

```
Player player[2];
whoPlays = initPlayerAttribution(&player[2], gamingMode);
```

And here's a part of the definition of the function in another C file where my crash appears :

```
int initPlayerAttribution(Player *tab1D[], int gamingMode)
{
    if(gamingMode == PLAYER_VS_AI)
    {
        strcpy(&(*tab1D[1]).pseudo, "AI");
        printf("Type the player1 name :\t");
        scanf("%s", (*tab1D[0]).pseudo);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Type the player1 name :\t");
        scanf("%s", (*tab1D[0]).pseudo);
        printf("Type the player2 name :\t");
        scanf("%s", (*tab1D[1]).pseudo);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It still seems difficult for me to understand pointer when you have a table with structures in and you have to send it to a function :x

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving the location of the end of you array, try entering just:

```
whoPlays = initPlayerAttribution(player, gamingMode);
```

And change your function to:

```
int initPlayerAttribution(Player *tab1D, int gamingMode)
{
    ...
}
```

Since your passing the pointer to your array, it will go fine. It is different than with normal ints.

What happens if you do:

```
whoPlays = initPlayerAttribution(&player[2], gamingMode);
```

Is giving an array to initPlayerAttribution which points to some memory address after your array. So what you are actually trying to access in initPlayerAttribution are player[2] and player[3].

Comment: Yes, I read your function wrong, see edit. You should change you function a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much it works pretty well :)
And you made me understand which's quite nice !
I'm gonna accept your answer asap timer is finished !

Answer (score 1):

```
Player player[2];
whoPlays = initPlayerAttribution(&player[2], gamingMode);
```

You are running out of bounds, arrays are base 0 ----^

Your function expects a pointer:

```
int initPlayerAttribution(Player *tab1D, int gamingMode)
```

or

```
int initPlayerAttribution(Player tab1D[], int gamingMode)
```

But not `Player *tab1D[]`,  thats an array of pointer to player

And you don't need to specify dimensions (array decays into pointer in your function) just:

```
whoPlays = initPlayerAttribution(player, gamingMode);
```

Comment: Thanks Alter Mann for your explanations :)